# What should be the intended behavior when trying to restore from savepoint in Kubernetes HA Flink Application cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, high-availability

I am running Flink 1.13.1 in High availability mode as a Application cluster deployment in Kubernetes. As the title reads, what should be the expected behavior when trying to supply `--fromSavepoint s3://../savepoints/savepoint-bd0cac-b89c95db0927` argument? What i have noticed is;

1. If i supply this argument but there is HA resource ConfigMap for the jobmanager leader, and a valid checkpoint. The job will ignore the supplied savepoint, but rather restore from last successful checkpoint.
2. If i remove all kubernetes resources (Deployment, Pods and ConfigMaps) for a specific job deploymentent, and supply `--fromSavepoint ...` argument, the job will restore from the supplied savepoint.

Is this the intended behavior? Do i need to remove all resources to be able to restore a HA cluster from savepoint?

Comment: I believe that Flink wants to restore from the latest snapshot, and will use the savepoint only if no newer checkpoint is found.